# LINQ and column with Null

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql, dataset

I have a `DataSet`, with a column, lets call it **A**, of type `Int`. I want to run a quiote simple `LINQ` query, using `where` on column **A**. The problem is, that column **A** can contain null values (at least in the `T-SQL` table from where i get it, I am not sure how these null values are translated in the `TableAdapter`). This results in an error when I try to run the following query:

```
MyTableDataTable dt =
    new MyTableDataTable();

MyTableTableAdapter ta =
     new MyTableTableAdapter();

        ta.Fill(dt);

// This is where the error occurs
var query = from  tbl in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where tbl.A == parentId 
            &&    tbl.B == languageId
            select new
            {
                tbl.A,
                tbl.B,
                tbl.C
            };
```

The error message it returns is this:

> **StrongTypingException was unhandled**
>
> An unhandled exception of type
>    'System.Data.StrongTypingException' occurred in
>   MyProgram.exe
>
> Additional information: The value for column 'A' in
>   table 'MyTable' is DBNull.

How should `null`values be handed in a sceniario like this? I would like to do something like `where A is not null`, but I can't really find a way to do this...

Comment: You want to do `where tbl.A != null`? Sound easy... :)

Comment: Since the value is DBNull `where tbl.A != DbNull.Value`

Comment: @Magnus that results in a syntax error: "Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'DBNull'"

Comment: In that case, `tbl.A` can never be `null`.

Comment: In that case the error must be coming from the `ta.Fill(dt);` Probably dataTable column `A` is `int` but should be `int?`

Comment: @Magnus that might very well be the case. I am quite new to `DataSet`'s, so I might have defined in incorrectly. It was possible to solve though, if you look at my answer below :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, by accident, when attempting @gencklavyeler's suggestion. While `tbl.A != null` does not work, there is another way using `tbl.IsANull() == false`. Like this:

```
var query = from  tbl in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where tbl.IsANull() == false
            &&    tbl.A == parentId 
            &&    tbl.B == session.LanguageId
            select new
            {
                tbl.A,
                tbl.B,
                tbl.C
            };
```

Comment: Hi @Noceo, did you try my answer as well?

Comment: There are deffinitly more to this, than I first though. Mainly the `int?` vs `int` discussion. So while this method solves the problem, I would recommend reading the other posts as well...

Answer (score 0):

You must check null before  `tbl.A == parentId` ,and there are benefits check `tbl.B`

```
var query = from  tbl in dt.AsEnumerable()
        where tbl.A != null && tbl.A == parentId 
        &&  tbl.B != null &&  tbl.B == languageId
        select new
        {
            tbl.A,
            tbl.B,
            tbl.C
        };
```

Comment: If I do that, I get a warning on that line saying: "The result of that expression is always 'true' since value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'"

Comment: @Noceo is `tbl.B` also nullable? If not you can just use `tbl.B == languageId` without checking on null

Comment: @AleksAndreev `tbl.B` can never me null, so the issue ís only related to column **A**.

Answer (score 0):

Try Code:

```
var query = from  tbl in dt.AsEnumerable()
        where tbl.Field<dynamic>("A") == parentId 
        &&    tbl.Field<dynamic>("B") == languageId
        select tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that **A** is `nullable`, so I assume in your definition you have something like:

```
int? A { get; set; }
```

or something similar. Note the(?) to make the property nullable. If that's set, then you can do:

```
var query = from  tbl in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where tbl?.A == parentId 
            &&    tbl.B == languageId
            select new
            {
                tbl.A,
                tbl.B,
                tbl.C
            };
```

Also note the (?) before property **A**. Another way is to use a `ternary operation` approach, for example:

```
var query = from  tbl in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where tbl.A == null ? true : tbl.A == parentId
            &&    tbl.B == languageId
            select new
            {
                tbl.A,
                tbl.B,
                tbl.C
            };
```

If property **A** is null, it resolves to true and skips to the next condition.

Comment: I have not tried to change the dataset, which I assume I would need to try your solution. However I think you are addressing the correct issue. That is, that while *A* is nullable in the database, I don't think it is nullable in the same way, in the dataset. Maybe if I changed the datatype to `int?` rather than `int`, it would work.

Comment: Yes, since A is nullable in the database I think it's important to match it to nullable as well on the dataset. You're right, my solution will work if A is explicitly defined as nullable(on the dataset). Let me know when you try it.

Comment: I used drag-and-drop design for the `DataSet`, which might not have been the best approach. I will let you know, if I revisit the `DataSet` design and try your solution. Thanks for the input.